# a command or script for changing encoded characters in a text file

Tags: text, file-format

I believe there are other options too, but I was wondering would it be possible to replace some characters in a text file with the Command line?
Example: 
è to č, æ to ć and so on...
Could I point a command to the specific text file and change those letters? Would it be possible to enter only one command with all the parameters specified or is it necessary to create a script?

Regards,
d.r.

Comment: The "standard" Unix utility for character transliteration is `tr` - however AFAIK it does not fully support multi-byte characters. For a thorough discussion (including alternatives using `sed` and `perl` see [tr analog for unicode characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389641/65304)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I found out how to replace the above mentioned charaters. The command was: sed -i 's/è/č/g' nameoffile.txt Now, the problem is that there are other characters in the file that I cannot paste into the Command line. If I do that character will transform in a different sign. More specific - this one is the problem:

Comment: I can't paste that character here, it looks like a square with numbers in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. I installed "enca", a cli program that helped me to detect the encoding of the textual files. 
Since they are all WINDOWS-1250 I did create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.srt; 
do iconv -f CP1250 -t UTF-8 -o "$file".utf "$file" && mv "$file".utf "$file"; 
done
```

Then I point the files that I need to convert and start the script. I hope this can help someone with a similar issue.